# Perl script to format .xls file in Linux

Tags: text-processing, perl, columns, mail-command, excel

All I have is a linux command (I don't know what's behind the command, the script or what formats the command output), so what I can do is to pull the data [which is in table form with invisible column lines], out from linux, and send it out to people for reviewing purpose.

When I run the command, the generated output are nicely formatted in aligned columns on my console screen, even when I put it into diff types of file extension: .txt / .csv / .xls (they are all nice in linux terminal)

> thatCommand | mail -s 'Statistics' my@email.com

Above: print output as message body in the email
Below: redirect output to a file and send it out as attachment in email

> thatCommand > stat.xls
>   uuencode stat.xls table.xls | \mail -s "Statistics" my@email.com

Then, I have this problem, 
after executing the first command line, the table in my message body is shown like below

> Student Name ID SubjectA(%) SubjectB(%)
>   Aaron Frank 7892 89 100
>   Benjamin Ayres 8892 78 90

How I would like it, to be arranged according to columns:

```
Student Name       ID   SubjectA(%) SubjectB(%)
Aaron Frank       7892      89         100
Benjamin Ayres    8892      78          90
```

So I tried 2nd command lines with attachment instead. After receiving those different types of file extension attachment in mail, save and open them in windows. (in my PC, csv and xls are by default open by excel, txt open using notepad)

The output supposed to be in different columns (it's a table in linux before I exported it),
but instead all the data is in the first column, looking messy in excel application. [looking messy in notepad too]

The below image is my endgoal, data values in different columns (well aligned)

[image: how it supposed to look like, how I expect it]

how it looked like now, the data are all in columnA only
[image: how it looked like now]

Is perl script able to help? So that I could get the nicely formatted output when received the attachment? I wouldn't mind because I still have to add some info at the end of the excel file in linux. (even though I have yet to figured out how to do that), but for now my main concern is on how to format it :)

This is the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355271/run-multiple-commands-and-put-into-different-excel-worksheets) question what would be further done.

Comment: not clear, but I think you just need to pipe the output to `column -t`

Comment: @Sundeep that will only work if the font that the email is rendered as is fixed width (which you can set). You could also use an HTML table.

Comment: You could also send the contents as an attachment

Comment: Hi DarkHeart, I have learned to : echo "testing" | mail -s "Test mail" user@example.com -a Desktop/attempt.txt (this is not working) 
Do you mean there is a way to send the output from running a command in terminal console window as attachment ?

Comment: Hi @DarkHeart, I have tried to save the output to both csv and text file, but the output is still the same. Not aligned. Would you shed some light on this?
Should I pipe the output into perl script and format from there?

Comment: Ok, the question title talks about "formatting an .xls file", but the examples in the end look like text files, which one is it? I think you are saying you want to create something that opens nicely in Excel? Does it have to be in a specific format (.xls, .xlsx, .csv) or does anything do? What format is your input in?

Comment: @santa - try `echo "testing" | mail -s "Test mail" -a blah.txt  user@example.com` or use `mailx`

Comment: Hi @ilkkachu, sorry I forgot to take away the previos example after I reedit the question. Yes, maybe 'format' it so that it displayed nicely in excel. I would prefer it in excel format, because I would like to put different command output into different worksheet in same workbook.

Comment: Hi @DarkHeart, I have tried using uuencode, mailx, and mail-s, but I still got the messy output. No matter its xls, csv or txt format.

Comment: Please don’t be upset by this question, but: do you have any idea what you are doing? If you do, you should explain more what you are doing. If not, you should break your problem down into smaller pieces and try to solve them individually. OK, you’ve made a good start at asking a clear question: you’ve said what you’re trying to achieve, and what result you’re getting. What’s lacking is: what are you doing? I don’t think we need to see the entire Perl script yet, but a few lines of it (where it writes the output file) might help. More importantly, you should show us the output file. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And tell us whether your email recipients are seeing the same file that you are sending (e.g., if they `TYPE` it, or open it in Notepad). And, backing up a little, what are you ***really*** trying to achieve?  Are you trying to get people to see your data in neat, aligned columns?  Or are you specifically trying to send them an Excel file, so they can open your file in Excel and use Excel to do things with it (including displaying your data in neat, aligned columns)? And what do you mean, “I have tried to save the output to both csv and text file”?  A csv file ***is*** a text file.

Comment: ... and Excel can open a CSV file, if the recipient chooses to do so. Consider outputting a proper CSV instead.

Comment: Hi@Scott, I have re-edit the question, with hope that I could get you to understand the whole picture. Yes, the recipients are receiving the same email, having the same problem. Yes, I want recipients to see a nicely, aligned column data. I apologize for not realizing csv is a text file. It was by default open using excel in my PC, so before you mentioned, I've always thought it was excel file. tq

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Perl itself can send emails, [see here for examples](https://learn.perl.org/examples/email.html), easier and less error prone.

Anyway, for your case, a HTML email body should work, e.g

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And to send HTML emails, you need to set the `content-type` header, [see here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010230/mailx-send-html-message)

Comment: thanks daisy! sorry that I wasn't clear in my question. I have a command, then I run it in console terminal to send the output(of the command) to mail, but it was not formatted. so sometimes, I would not know, if that person is Adam and who has that amount of files.

Comment: The OP is clearly confused.   IMNSHO, you compounded that confusion by making up your own data.   Why didn’t you use the OP’s data from the question (e.g., “Aaron Frank” and 7892)?

Comment: Hi @Scott, daisy was actually replied by using my previous edited question's data. And I have edited the question in attempt to get people to understand my whole picture. thanks